# Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I installed cuda and cudnn of v12.2 with anaconda (python version 3.10.12) enviroment. now i am installing tensorflow-GPU version 2.6 but unfortunetly I am getting error :
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

how to fix it kindly guide me.

in the already available anaconda enviroment tensorflow was installed. so i created new enviroment but the error persist.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you are installing incompatible tensorflow version (2.6) in Python 3.10

`Tensorflow 2.6` is compatible to run with `python 3.6 - 3.9` where as you can install `Tensorflow 2.8 - 2.10` for the existing installed `python version 3.10` as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

Please see the below screenshot for the configuration details.[image]